# ¿Cómo limitar los caracteres introducidos en input con select2?

Tags: jquery, regex, select2

Estoy usando la librería **Select2** para crear tags y lo que me gustaría es **limitar la longitud de los caracteres** de los tags en mi input. Por ejemplo:

Me gustaría limitarlo a 10 caracteres.

Si el usuario introduce **"manzana"**, se crearía el tag ya que tiene una longitud de **7 caracteres**

Pero si el usuario introduce: **"paralelepipedo"**, entonces no se debería crear el tag en el input ya que **sobrepasa los 10 caracteres** (la palabra tiene 12 caracteres)

Este es mi código jquery para mi select2 y funciona perfectamente, sin embargo busco que el usuario no coloque una palabra tan extensa para crear tags.

```
$("#customer_tag_ids").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 5,
    multiple: true,
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (params) {
      if (params.term.match(/^(?![\d ])[a-z\d ]*$/i)) {
        // Return null to disable tag creation
        return {
          id: params.term,
          text: params.term,
          tag: true
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
    language: {
      maximumSelected: function (e) {
        return I18n.t('customer.alert.limit_max');
      },

      inputTooShort: function (e) {
        return I18n.t('customer.alert.limit_min');
      },

      noResults: function(){
        return I18n.t('customer.alert.not_result_found');
      }
    },
  });
```

Si alguien sabe y me puede ayudar estaría enormemente agradecido

Feliz día.

Comment: No se en que tiene que ve esta pregunta con rails. No he ocupado select2, pero has probado con [`maximumInputLength`](https://select2.org/searching#maximum-search-term-length)?

Comment: Esa gema es frecuentemente usada en la comunidad de Rails, por eso la etiqueta, y como en la versión de ingles de stackoverflow lo relacionan mucho.

Ya he intentado maximumInputLenght pero no me sirve. Pero si intenté algo simple de jquery

var text = params.term;
if (text.length > 14){
  return null
}

Si sobrepasa el límite no retorna nada. Luego con el atributo "noResults" le dices que sobrepasó el límite.

Gracias por tu tiempo y por responder. Es practica el select2 si necesitas crear etiquetas por cada palabra que coloques en el input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   createTag: function (params) {
      var text = params.term;
      if (text.length > 14){
        return null
      }
    }
```

Listo, con tomar el texto del usuario pude resolver.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).